# php-css editing for image resize (wordpress theme)

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress, edit

I need your help with the following theme.

http://www.korevolution.com/risorse-gratuite/free-wp-theme/koresponsive/

I want to change the size of the images on index page and also the size of image on each post.

I found the code below on functions.php and stylesheet.css,bust just editing it isnt enough.

```
Functions.php code

add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'link', 'gallery', 'status', 'quote', 'image' ) );
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 314, 200, true );
add_image_size( 'related', 50, 50, true ); 
add_image_size( 'home_img', 314, 200, true ); 
add_image_size( 'single_img', 600, 300, true );  
add_image_size( 'page_img', 920, 350, true ); 
add_image_size( 'slider_img', 600, 280, true ); 

Stylesheet.css code

.img-home, .feat-thumb a
max-width: 314px;
max-height: 200px;
display: inline-block;

.img-single, .feat-thumb-s a
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 300px;
display: inline-block;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: fyi, just remember that all uploaded images have your old size settings applied to them, so changing size with `add_image_size()` will affect NEW images only. if you want consistency, you will have to delete old images, and reload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the CSS should do it... when I change the value of the `max-width` property of `.feat-thumb a` to something smaller in Chrome I see it resize as expected.  You may not be editing it correctly (for example you may not have server-side file permissions set up to save edits made to templates through the Wordpress admin panel - try FTP instead), or you may be seeing a cached stylesheet and need to clear your browser's cache to load the updated stylesheet.

The `add_image_size()` references in `functions.php` for `home_img` and `single_img` are only used when an image is first uploaded, so it is not retroactive so in order to update images uploaded previously you need to use a plugin - I like this one: [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

However, in a responsive theme, images are generally set to either `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%` (in this case the latter) and depend on the size of their parent container or in some cases a more distant ancestor container, which is why you are updating the CSS value for `.feat-thumb a`, the anchor element that wraps the `img`, rather than the `img` directly, so in many cases just updated `add_image_size()` wouldn't be enough without CSS tweaks as well (and really, changing the calls to `add_image_size()` wouldn't matter because regardless of actual size the images in a responsive design will generally never be more than 100% the width of their smaller container).

If you are certain the CSS update is being applied/loaded (e.g. you can inspect it in your browser from the server and it's not a file permissions or cache issue) you can try adding `!important` to the end of the styles (sloppy) or copy and paste them at the end of the stylesheet and add another element to the selector chain to ensure they are of higher specificity (e.g. `body .feat-thumb a` rather than `.feat-thumb a`).  However I suspect you are having some other issue because as I said I can see the results on the front end when I modify the CSS directly in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks now its working. I had to edit both php and css and then i used the plugin,which made things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the images through WordPress' image editor & settings.  Once you've done that, your CSS should work

Go to your Wordpress Medial Library (your_website.com/wp-admin/upload.php) to edit your uploaded image files

Here is where you can find [WordPress image settings help](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_Screen)